# React state is resetting in react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-state

My problem is that the state in my react context is resetting on every render. I thought that's not the thing behind react context and global states. Well I don't know how to fix that.

When I log the "Hi", it get's logged every time the child component is rendered and of course the alerts state is resetted to the empty array.

Here is my root layout:

```
export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en" className='bg-base-300'>
            <body className={`${inter.className} bg-base-300`}>
                <NextAuthProvider>
                    <AlertProvider>
                        <Navbar>
                            {children}
                        </Navbar>
                    </AlertProvider>
                </NextAuthProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

That's my AlertProvider and my AlertContext:

```
export const AlertContext = createContext<{
    alerts: Alert[],
    setAlerts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Alert[]>>
}>({
    alerts: [],
    setAlerts: () => { }
});

const AlertProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    console.log("Hi")
    const [ alerts, setAlerts ] = useState<Alert[]>([]);

    return (
        <AlertContext.Provider value={{alerts, setAlerts}}>
            {children}
        </AlertContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

EDIT: More information

In my `Commands`-component I call the context and pass it into a method which has alerts and setAlerts as parameters. In that addAlert method I call the setAlerts and that works. But only with one alert at the same time.

In my Commands component:

```
addAlert(new Alert("error", `There was an error while deleting ${commandName} command.`, null), alertClass.alerts, alertClass.setAlerts);
```

The addAlert Method:

```
export const addAlert = (alert: Alert, alerts: Alert[], setAlerts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Alert[]>>) => {
    
// Some unimportant code


        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            removeAlert(
                alerts.findIndex(
                    (alert) =>
                        alert.type === alert.type && alert.message === alert.message
                ),
                alerts,
                setAlerts
            );
        }, 10000);
        const newAlert: Alert = { type: alert.type, message: alert.message, timeout: timeoutId };
        setAlerts([
            ...alerts,
            newAlert
        ])
    
}
```

Comment: Where do you call setAlerts?

Comment: What happens inside the `NextAuthProvider`, the `Navbar` and how do you use the `RootLayout` ?

Comment: I added some more details, thank you for the quick answer! @DanielBank

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli In the `NextAuthProvider` only contains a user object because of the `SessionProvider`. It is used to verify that the user is registred and logged in to display the correct information. Like for admins and user roles. The `navbar` is a server component which does not contain any client side stuff but contains children components. I don't know how I use the `RootLayout`, that's only the standard configuration and I do not handle other specific stuff with it.

Comment: I agree with @GabrielePetrioli it seems that it depends how and where you call `RootLayout`. and maybe `RootLayout` has been re-rendered by calling some other componets?

Comment: @Jerry I don't call RootLayout by myself or I just don't know it. But I think it only is called once when the app starts

Comment: @Dave I think `NextAuthProvider` will re-render if auth state changed and then `AlertProvider` as its child will be re-render as well. what about level up `AlertProvider` to the top of `NextAuthProvider`

Comment: @Jerry I tried that already before but it didn't work. I solved it now with redux and that works now exactly how I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

## How I solved my problem

So I decided not to use useContext with useRef and looked at redux.

Since I'm using **Next.js 13**, it had to be approached a bit differently since redux can only be used client-side.

In the app folder I created a globals folder by creating the following files:

- provider.tsx
- store.ts
- features/alertSlice.ts
- logic/alertLogic.ts

**All files must be marked with `'use client';` otherwise they will be recognized as server components.**

I imported the provider from provider.tsx into layout.tsx:

```
// provider.tsx
"use client";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store';

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

```
// layout.tsx

import { Providers } from './globals/provider';

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en" className='bg-base-300'>
            <body className={`${inter.className} bg-base-300`}>
                <Providers>
                    <NextAuthProvider>
                        <Navbar>
                            {children}
                        </Navbar>
                    </NextAuthProvider>
                </Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

My AlertSlice includes 2 reducer actions, one to add and one to remove an alert.

```
// alertSlice.tsx
"use client";

import { Alert } from "@/lib/classes/Alert";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface AlertState {
    alerts: Alert[];
}

const initialState: AlertState = {
    alerts: [],
};

export const alertSlice = createSlice({
    name: "alert",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addAlert: (state, action) => {
            state.alerts.push(action.payload);
        },

        removeAlert: (state, action) => {
            const indexToRemove = state.alerts.findIndex(
                (alert) =>
                    alert.message === action.payload.message &&
                    alert.type === action.payload.type
            );
            if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
                state.alerts.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
            }
        },
    },
});

export const { addAlert, removeAlert } = alertSlice.actions;

export default alertSlice.reducer;
```

But I want the alerts to disappear automatically after 10 seconds and setting the timeout in the reducer actions doesn't work, so I had to write a helper function, which I call and removes the alerts after 10 seconds:

```
// alertLogic.ts
export const addAlertLogic = (alert: Alert, dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addAlert(alert));
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(removeAlert(alert));
    }, 10000);
};
```

So I can call a single function with the alert and the passed dispatcher (because you can only call it in components) and the alert is added and removed after 10 seconds, and that even across components.

```
addAlertLogic({
            type: 'info',
            message: 'Test',
            timeout: null
        }, dispatch);
```

Answer (score -1):

Context api causes all the components inside the context to re-render each time the context changes and this can cause that problems, that's why the use of context is not recommended as a first solution for a problem that could be solved with redux or zustand. Anyways, if you still want to use context you will have to use UseRef to hold a reference to your state variables and persist them between all the renders caused by the context.

There are several blogs where you can learn more about why you shouldn't use context to handle states or why you should use context to solve other kind of problems and if its worth it.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I will take a look to some information about it :)